# How To Read A File As Stream In Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

Ok so am currently working on this project for an android app and I'm using ionic, but my problem is, I need to read a file as a stream and i was wondering how this could be done using the ionic native file plugin or any other means.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the [Fileopener](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/file-opener) plugin?

In most cases just `fileOpener.open(path+filename,'application/pdf')` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks will try that and see

Comment: Actually what I need is the stream results itself, am going to pass it to a method that requires it

Comment: I am looking to have a function like fs.createReadStream() in Ionic. I think this question is related to my problem.